# Android touch events

Tags: android, events, sdk, touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android long-touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553163/android-long-touch-event)

I want to be able to touch (and hold) the screen, and have an event be triggered by this.
This is what I have so far.

```
class Player extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback 
{

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
         return true;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this only recognizes when the touch is 'moving' not when its stationary and held. I don't know what to do with touch events.

Comment: yesterday I was looking for drag&drop feature, i.e. for a listview. I think the behaviour is similar to touch&hold what you described. Maybe this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort/2909341#2909341

Comment: There's several different versions of gesturelistener. I'm not sure which one SurfaceView should use. It's kind of confusing

Comment: The MotionEvent has what you want - getAction() will return ACTION_DOWN when you press, and you can consider the touch held until you get another event with ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL.

Comment: Thanks, my problem was within the drawing of my graphics.