# Scrolling integer with long click - Android

Tags: android, scroll, onlongclicklistener

I am new to android development. I'm trying to make a program that the user selects red green and blue values to make a custom color. I have everything working the way I want but one pesky thing. When the user holds a value down or up button I want the values to keep changing. So far this is what I got

```
redUpButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            if(redColorValue<250){
                redColorValue+=5;
                redTextField.setText(""+redColorValue/5);
                mainColorLabel.setTextColor(Color.rgb(redColorValue, greenColorValue, blueColorValue));
                }//ends if
            return true;
        }//ends method
    });//ends click listener
```

but when I do this it only changes my values once. How do i get it to keep changing the values while I hold the button. I assume I need a while statement but nothing I try works.

Comment: you will have to use threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnLongClickListener` is an event like any other which is only called once per press. Hence, the event in not a looping mechanism to increment something but only a custom event for long touch

Instead you can try the `onTouchListener` with `onKeyListener` to achieve the above

See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553163/android-long-touch-event) here