# Different ways to handle button view in android

Tags: android

Well I m pretty new in android,so it might be the basic question.

I just created my own button (let say "increment"). Which on being pressed increases the counter and on being released it get stop.

Comment: You can provide size, position,background, click event

Comment: what do you want to ask?

Comment: Do you mean like the Date/Time Picker, where holding the button down auto-repeats?

Comment: can you please elaborate your concern? there are many people here who wanted to help you. please provide example or any illustration.

Comment: @KenY-N: Exactly my point being, lets just say i want this in button fashion not in date/time picker format.

I just need a simple logic or method kind off stuffs.

Example: There is a TextView = text;
(2 buttons  ) Button increment, decrements;
now if i use increment.setOnClickListner(){
//Some stuffs,probably counter++;
now if i close the statement,what will happen when i click the button "increment" the textview will display counter + 1.
And i have to repeatedly hit the button to increase counter.I just it automatically, i.e. when i hit button counter increase and when i release it stop.

Comment: @Sidharth - [Here is a similar question with a complete answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284224/android-hold-button-to-repeat-action). Does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean if you hold the button, It will increases the counter?
Implement this [Android long-touch event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553163/android-long-touch-event)

Comment: I just need a simple logic or method kind off stuffs.

Example: There is a TextView = text;
(2 buttons  ) Button increment, decrements;
now if i use increment.setOnClickListner(){
//Some stuffs,probably counter++;
now if i close the statement,what will happen when i click the button "increment" the textview will display counter + 1.
And i have to repeatedly hit the button to increase counter.I just want it automatically, i.e. when i hit button counter increase and when i release it stop.