# Drag&Drop to put Items from List1 to List2

Tags: android, user-interface, drag-and-drop

I search for a good and handy user interface to put items from list 1
to a empty list 2 with drag&drop. I need this function for Android 2.2.

Have anybody heard about this feature?

**EDIT**
I found this website and i think it is also interesting.
http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/simple-drag-n-drop-on-android.html
Look also at the comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. It may also be helpful to reference my simple Drag and Drop list. You can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort)
2. if u don't getting then use this

   An example of this in github https://github.com/mtparet/Drag-And-Drop-Android

   It could help you.All contribution are welcome
3. Take a look at this sample that [Drag and drop](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/10/experience-android-drag-and-drop-list.html) inside a List View..

Comment: Thank you Mike for your help. The second link looks interesting.

Comment: If anybody has more good infos about my question, than you are welcome, but for this moment, i think all interesting thinks are in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the drag and drop API launched in API Version 11
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html

A drag and drop operation starts when the user makes some gesture that you recognize as a signal to start dragging data. In response, your application tells the system that the drag is starting. The system calls back to your application to get a representation of the data being dragged. As the user's finger moves this representation (a "drag shadow") over the current layout, the system sends drag events to the drag event listener objects and drag event callback methods associated with the View objects in the layout. Once the user releases the drag shadow, the system ends the drag operation.

Comment: I know that this feature is available since api level 11, but sometimes a workaround for such a problem exists. I know one to sort a list with drag&drop, but not for my problem.

Comment: @Happo I don't know about any written code.. i'm sure its can be done though.. if you unable to find it on the web I think you'll have to try stitching it together using the sort code you already have (probably the one used by google's music app). and hope for better days when we could just forget about pre-API11 machines..