# Listview item drag out

Tags: android

I have a follow-up question with @Commonsware regarding this post:

[Android List View Drag and Drop sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort/10764149)

or if anyone find a way to drag the item outside the listview using commonsware component may want to share their solution.

thanks.