# How to set both lines of a ListView using simple_list_item_2?

Tags: android, android-widget

So the following will create a ListView where the rows have their "primary" textview filled by the values array.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Changing the third parameter to android.R.id.text2 sets the "secondary" textview. Is there any simple way to set both?

Answer (score 123):

This questions ranks high with Google but I consider the given answer to be way too complicated. As pointed out in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062569/how-to-construct-and-display-the-info-in-simple-list-item-2) answers, the desired functionality can be achieved using ArrayAdapter with a very easy trick.

You can override the getView method of the ArrayAdapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list) {
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

    text1.setText(persons.get(position).getName());
    text2.setText(persons.get(position).getAge());
    return view;
  }
};
```

If you didn't notice: the trick is to supply `android.R.id.text1` as (principally unneccessary) parameter, otherwise the call to `super` will cause an exception.

Also, this solution does not make use of `TwoLineListItem`, which was deprecated in API 17.

Comment: Thank this worked! The `list` variable passed to the `ArrayAdapter` is never really used though.

Comment: Yes, TwoLineListItem was deprecated but don't think that it is somehow related to SimpleCursorAdapter just because they were used together in Vipul's example.  SimpleCursorAdapter is a very useful, generic ListAdapter implementation that iterates through Cursor rows, mapping the given columns to the given layout views.  It should generally be preferred over writing your own ListAdapter when populating a ListView from a Cursor.  Although, even if you aren't using a Cursor, it might not be out of the question to use a SimpleCursorAdapter and wrap your data in a MatrixCursor.

Comment: You are right, TwoLineListItem is not related to SimpleCursorAdapter. I included the remark simply because TwoLineListItem is used in two other answers. My solution is for simple, short lists only. More advanced solutions will e.g. make use of the ViewHolder pattern, too.

Comment: Will this solution will slow on large lists? Is it using recycling somehow?

Comment: Yes, this solution will be slow for large lists, see comment from Feb 25.

Comment: Just as an extra note, if you make the `toString` function of person return `getName()`, then the super will fill in the name part for you.

Comment: Thank you @winne2, this solution just ended 5 days of searching the internet.

Comment: Just to give some more details for Newbies like me: persons needs to be declared final,

Comment: what does list refer to? Is that dummy too?

Comment: see first comment and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int, int, java.util.List<T>)

Answer (score 5):

hope this help you

```
ArrayAdapter<CustomObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CustomObject> (_context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, listCustomObject) {

                                @Override
                                public View getView(int position,
                                        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                                    View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                                    TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                                    TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                                    text1.setText(listCustomObject.get(position).getText1());

                                    text2.setText( listCustomObject.get(position).getText2() );

                                    return view;
                                }

                            };
```

Answer (score 2):

can try this as well....

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,values){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

               TwoLineListItem   row = (TwoLineListItem)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                row.getText1().setText(values.get***());
                row.getText2().setText(values.get****());

                return row;
            }
        };
    setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, but this did: http://www.sethgholson.com/2012/01/using-simple_list_item_2-with-an-arrayadapter-android/

Comment: @Timmmm the `super.getView()` method takes care of that.

Comment: @JasonRobinson Clearly not. It isn't even passed those parameters.

Comment: @Timmmm True, but seeing as there isn't a `getView()` method in `ArrayAdapter` with no parameters, the intent was clearly to call the super `getView` method with all parameters. I've edited the answer to remove the ambiguity.

Comment: Note: TwoLineListItem was deprecated for API 17 - Android 4.2