# How to construct and display the info in simple_list_item_2?

Tags: android, android-layout

I get the list of customer info from my (testing) database, and I want to display it. The customer is represented by the `Customer` class with `name`, `info`, and `note` members. Its `toString` method returns only the `name`. I have created the `DemoDatabaseMainActivity` that uses the `simple_list_item_1` layout only, thus displaying only the `name` of a customer -- like this:

```
public class DemoDatabaseMainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private CustomerDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new CustomerDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Customer> values = datasource.getAllCustomers();

        ArrayAdapter<Customer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Customer>(this,
                                   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
...
}
```

It works just fine; however, I'd like to learn the next step...

I would like to modify the code so that I could use the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2` where `name` would be at the first line, and the `info` + `note` at the second line? What should be implemented instead of the `Customer.toString()`, and what adapter or whatever should I use?

**Update** based on Patric's comment https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062742/1346705 -- with respect to that, I have hoped for the modified solution like that:

```
public class DemoDatabaseMainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private CustomerDataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        datasource = new CustomerDataSource(this);
        datasource.open();

        List<Customer> values = datasource.getAllCustomers();

        TwolineAdapter adapter = new TwolineAdapter(this, values);  // here the difference
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
...
}
```

So, I have added my `TwolineAdapter` class this way:

```
public class TwolineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Customer> {

    private List<Customer> objects;

    public TwolineAdapter(Context context, List<Customer> objects) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

        text1.setText(objects.get(position).getName());
        text2.setText(objects.get(position).getInfo() 
                      + " (" + objects.get(position).getNote() + ")");
        return view;
    }
}
```

But it did not work (apparently because of some of my errors). Notice the `simple_list_item_2` in the `super` constructor code call. When running, the code shows the error log message like:

```
E/ArrayAdapter(27961): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
```

I would like to ask you where the problem is. Trying to find the reason, I have modified the `TwolineAdapter` to work the same way as the original with the `simple_list_item_1`

```
public class TwolineAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Customer> {

    private List<Customer> objects;

    public TwolineAdapter(Context context, List<Customer> objects) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView view  = (TextView)super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        view.setText(objects.get(position).getInfo());  // displaying a different info
        return view;
    }
}
```

To be sure the overriden `getView` works, I have displayed a different part of the customer info. And it worked fine. In other words, instead of the general `toString` method, the result of my specific `getInfo` was displayed.

Anyway, I need to use the `simple_list_item_2`. What next should I do? (My conclusion is I am doing something wrong in the constructor. Am I right? Where is the problem?)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can override the `getView` method of the `ArrayAdapter`:

```
  new ArrayAdapter (context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, list)
  {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
      TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
      text1.setText("1");
      text2.setText("2");
      return view;
    }
  })
```

Comment: I see. It is right in the `ArrayAdapter` doc (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). If I understand you well, I should create my own class that will extend the `ArrayAdapter<Customer>`. Its `getView` will be the override that you suggest, right?

Comment: Thanks, Patric, for the hint. Please, have a look at the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) tutorial on how to create a custom listView. Being a beginner it starts you from the new project stage, I think it would help you. As for what you should use instead of your `toString()` method, just create in your `Customer` class some getters to retrieve the data. Something like this:

```
public String getName(){
return this.name;
}
```

And use it in your code like this:

```
 Customer x = new Customer();
//return the customer name into a string, obviously you will return it in a list that you will pass it to the listview
String customerName = x.getName();
```

Comment: Thanks, Cosmin, for the hints. (+1)