# Can simple_list_item_2 be customized?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, customization

I've used simple_list_item_2 in my code to create listview.Everything is working alright, but i want to change the background color of the layout.Is it possible? Can this layout also be customized like user defined XML?

Comment: IMO you cannot , but you can create another layout with the same code, and then replace the background of the simple_list_item_2 and then change it with the color you want, and then instead of call simple_list_item_2 call your new layout and it will work.

Comment: Just provide your custom row layout.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm creating another layout

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16062569/how-to-construct-and-display-the-info-in-simple-list-item-2 this may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your own `simple_list_item_2` like this, and use it instead

```
<TwoLineListItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   <!-- This is your background color-->
   android:background="#DC143C"

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
   android:mode="twoLine"
   android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
   android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd">
      <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem" />
      <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
             android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/text1"
             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSecondary" />
 </TwoLineListItem>
```

(Taken from the [android source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml))

Comment: thanks! I'm creating new layout based on your answer

Comment: I'm getting error in this line as my current min is 11.Is there anything else to replace this? 

android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"

Answer (score 1):

IMO you cannot , but you can create another layout with the same code, and then replace the background of the `simple_list_item_2` and then change it with the color you want, and then instead of call `simple_list_item_2` call your new layout and it will work.

EDIT*

Following the answer of @JonasCz, you can edit it and a sample code to replace it would be like :

```
ListView l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
String[] values = new String[] { "Ubuntu", "Android", "iPhone",
    "Windows", "Ubuntu", "Android", "iPhone", "Windows" };
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.your_custom_simple_list_item_2, values); //removed the android. 
viewContainer = findViewById(R.id.undobar);
l.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The code is from [AndroidListView/article.html](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)