# Creating a multicolumn Listview (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android

I have a file named "music.txt" in directory res/raw. It contains a list of songs and authors separated by ";", like this:

Bohemian rhapsody;Queen

Piano man;Billy Joel

Born to run;Bruce Springsteen

I want to use the file to populate a multicolumn ListView. Currently it works with the first column, so it shows only the name of the song, and I don't know how to implement the second column. I tried to replace the "activity_list_item" layout from the ArrayAdapater for a custom layout so I could place two elements on the same row inside TextViews, but it doesn't seem to work (it can't find the layout I created).

Here is the code:

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    list = findViewById(R.id.musicList);

    loadData();

}

public void loadData(){
    List<String> musicArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;

    InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.music);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    try {
        if (is != null) {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                musicArray.add(line.split(";")[0]);
            }
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String data[] = musicArray.toArray(new String[musicArray.size()]);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1, data);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

My custom LinearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main3Activity"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="TextView"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="TextView"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Comment: "it can't find the layout I created" – Try cleaning and rebuilding the project (under the Build menu), and if that doesn't work, Invalidate Caches/Restart (under File). There's a glitch in recent Android versions with newly created layouts.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't work. Just in case I'm doing something wrong: I created the layout in res/layout as a layout resource file. Seems like the obvious place but maybe it's not, is that the place where this type of layout should be?

Comment: Yep, that's it. It'd go in the same place as the other layouts you're using; e.g., `R.layout.activity_main2`.

Comment: First of all, your list contains only the names of singers. Create an object and fill your list accordingly. Then follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18529511/8956604). Or my idea is that you should use custom adapter.

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't find the layout I created"?  What exactly is happening?

Comment: The question is solved don't worry. In case anyone has the same issue: I was using "android.R.layout.your_custom_layout_id" instead of "R.layout.your_custom_layout_id".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create music object:

```
class Music {
    String name;
    String song;

    public Music(String name, String song) {
        this.name = name;
        this.song = song;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSong() {
        return song;
    }

    public void setSong(String song) {
        this.song = song;
    }
}
```

Change your list:

```
ArrayList<Music> musicList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Fill your list:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      String [] array = line.split(";");
      musicList.add(new Music(array[0],array[1]));
}
```

And your adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.your_custom_layout_id, R.id.textView1, musicList) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            text1.setText(musicList.get(position).getName());
            text2.setText(musicList.get(position).getSong());
            return view;
        }
    };

list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager`

```
GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 4); // change number of columns as you want
layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it appears red and tells me to create parameters and variables.

Answer (score 0):

You're right that you will need to define your own list item layout. This will be accessed in your class via `R.` not `android.R.`.

You will also need to define your own Adapter, by extending the `ArrayAdapter` class. In this new adapter you will define how to split your Strings and present them in 2 distinct `TextView` views within your custom layout.