# Is there something like a ListView that allows dynamic relocation of ListView elements drag-and-drop style?

Tags: android, listview

I am having a hard time describing this in a way Google will understand. Is there a list object that has the capability to drag a List element and move it up or down to the desired location?

Comment: you could take a custom adapter, and by clicking on listview item give the popup to swap,move or delete from the list, but making it accessible by drag and drop is really innovative one, hope you can make it, all the tricks can be done in custom adapter..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ya. check  this link out : https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-touchlist.
Actually this has been implemented in the Android Music application. Just take a look at the source code as well.

Please make sure you research your question before posting. This has been discussed a lot of times in stack overflow.. possible duplicates here :
[Android List View Drag and Drop sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909311/android-list-view-drag-and-drop-sort)
[How can I allow a user to re-sort items in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290000/how-can-i-allow-a-user-to-re-sort-items-in-a-list)